# AVL Tree height as a function of nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am trying to find the way to find out the height of the AVL tree as a function of his nodes.

I want to know if it is possible to make an AVL Tree at the height of 4 with exactly 11 nodes. I know that the upper bound of height of an AVL tree which is approximately 1.44*logn. So if I have 11 nodes it is actually 4.32. And yet, I am trying to built one with height 4 for at least 2 hours and fail to do so every time.

Answer (score 0):

Build full binary tree of height 4 with 15 nodes.

[image]

Remove ANY four nodes from the last level. Now it is valid AVL tree (the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one). Note that it's impossible to remove a node from 3rd level (together with childs, of course) and preserve AVL balance criteria.

One variant (from wiki):

[image]

Comment: Well, i am not sure if our proffesor is wrong or what is that standard but in our class the trees you've mentioned are height 3, I need to find out if it can happen if there will be at least another node (height 5 for you). Thanks in regards